# Change perPage limit

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pagination

By default per page pagination in Laravel = 15 item.

I want use custom variable `$perPage`, but want set limit, for example 500 item.

How it realize for all quires and not for only one method?

Comment: Which code are you using for pagination? Please include few lines...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to limit results, use [`take()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) with [`paginate()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#basic-usage). For example:

```
Model::take(500)->paginate(30)
```

Comment: And I must re-write all my method? And i don't wan't limit all object in query, but want limit perPage count of object.

Comment: @bipipoh what exactly methods are you talking about? If you just want to limit items per page, just do something like `Model::paginate(500)`

Comment: For example, I want `Model::paginate(499)` - return query where perPage 499, if I want `Model::paginate(501)` - return query with perPage 500, because limit - 500.

Comment: I think about redefine some method from builder.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not clear what exactly you want to implement.

Comment: But how it realize? When I use like this `Model::paginate($perPage)` and get variable from request - anyone can set `$perPage = over9000` and it kill DB server. And that I want to set limit for $perPage globally then re-write all my method with query.

Comment: @bipipoh you shouldn't get this variable from the request. Just do something like `Model::paginate(500)` and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Model::latest()->paginate(number of results each page);
```